# HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress returns 127.0.0.1 on the server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm hosting a simple web API with per-ip-address rate limitting.

The issue I'm having is - every request seems to return '127.0.0.1' as it's remote IP address when I print it via this code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"The IP {httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}");
```

The whole thing isn't hosted behind any reverse proxy, I'm just using Kestrel with such setup:

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000", "https://0.0.0.0:5001")
                    //.UseIISIntegration()
                    //.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/wwwroot")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

No matter if it's me or my friends connecting, it always pops `127.0.0.1`

Comment: this seems to be impossible if you are not running behind a reverse proxy, I think you can follow this docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1#troubleshoot to check the http header you actually received in server to see if there is any thing goes wrong in your environment, maybe there is a proxy in your network you don't know its existance and that proxy will handle the http request

Comment: @ElendilZheng-MSFT Yes, I have eventually set up a reverse proxy with header forwarding and it worked.